# How to get read headers in node.js using body-parser?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, body-parser, get-headers

I am tring to create a demo API server using `node.js`, `express4` and `body-parser`. I am trying to secure it using some `Api-Key` which will have to be passed in the request header. However, I am not able to do it.

I tried

```
console.log(bodyParser.getheader("Api-Key"))
```

and

```
console.log(app.getheader("Api-Key"))
```

but in both cases I get the error

```
getheader is not a function
```

So now can I read headers using body parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `.getHeader()`. To get the headers of a request, use `req.get()` (or its alias `req.header()`). For example:

```
var app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.get('Api-Key'))
  next()
})
```

See [the Express 4 docs for `req`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) for more information.

Comment: But I will have to do that in all requests, I want to do it oin a common place, and if this fails, not move forward

Comment: If you want a middleware to execute for every request, don't provide a route. (I've updated the answer to show this.)